# Code for calculating the intersections between a line segment and a trimesh

Tags: c++, c, 3d, computational-geometry

I am looking for a good library (preferably in C/C++) that can calculate the intersections between a line segment (ray) and a trimesh.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) is probably overkill, but I suggest it just for reference. The [documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/contents.html) is somewhat intimidating, but [this chapter](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/AABB_tree/Chapter_main.html) could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling led me to [GIMPACT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpact/) (Sourceforge link, not sure if they have an official website)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [this](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0105/algorithm_0105.htm)? There is an C++ example on that page as well (`intersect_RayTriangle`).